# How do I insert a commit between two commits on a different branch?

Tags: git

My repository started with a single commit:

```
A
```

Then I created the branch "refactor" and added another commit:

```
A
 \
  B
```

Then I switched back to master and changed some stuff:

```
A--C
 \
  B
```

I want commit C to exist on branch "refactor" between the first and second commits, so it looks like the branch occurred after C. Something like this:

```
A--C
    \
     B
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your refactor branch onto master.

```
$ git checkout refactor
$ git rebase master
```

but make sure `refactor` is a local branch, as `rebase` changes the commit history.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a rebase

```
$ git checkout refactor
$ git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a simple rebase:

```
git rebase master refactor
```

This will first check out refactor, then take the commits `master..refactor` (which should only contain B), and re-apply them on master.